# not able to view foreign key constrain in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i am using `symfony 2` and `doctrine` to create enitity class with a foreign key

here is my entity class , now the issue is when i check the table `fos_user` in mysql database , i don't see `travel_access_token` and `travel_id` as a foreign key and even if i change the value of `travel_id` in `fos_user` table database is not raising any issues.

i have **one to one unidirectional** relation as only one user can have one token only

```
<?php

namespace Travel\HomeBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_access_token;



     /** 

     @ORM\Column(name="travel_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Travel\HomeBundle\Entity\Client") 
     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="travel_id", referencedColumnName="id") 

     */

    protected $travel_id;


    /** 

      @ORM\Column(name="travel_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) 
      @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Travel\HomeBundle\Entity\Client")
      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="travel_access_token", referencedColumnName="secret")

     */

    protected $travel_access_token;




    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As "targetEntity" try use just the names of entities. Like this:

```
 @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Client")
```